# Center an item horizontally and have the items next to it centered vertically in bulma

Tags: html, css, bulma

I would like to center an image or an icon horizontally and have the other elements positioned next to it like in the image below:

[image: Example]

Here is the code I used :

```
  <div class="columns">
        <div class="column">
          <p class="bd-notification is-primary">ICON GOES HERE</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <p class="bd-notification is-primary">TEXT GOES HERE</p>
          <p class="bd-notification is-primary">Some text</p>
          <button (click)="onSelect()" class="button is-link">Select</button>
          <p>{{ select }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.columns {
  display: flex;
}
.forImg {
  max-height: 250px;
  border-radius : 50%;
}

.forInfos {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="columns">
        <div class="column forImg">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" class="image-circle image-center">
        </div>
        <div class="column forInfos">
          <p class="bd-notification is-primary">TEXT GOES HERE</p>
          <p class="bd-notification is-primary">Some text</p>
          <button (click)="onSelect()" class="button is-link">Select</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this either in an style tag in head section or in an external css file:

```
.columns { 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}
.column{
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```